# multiple form validation error message in single alert message javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve functionality of showing multiple validation error messages in single alert message.

i have three text fields, checking whether user entered a value or not in that text field. 
if user does not entered any value and tries to submit form,  I have to show to the user that three field are mandatory.

piece of code as below :

```
function validateInput(ele, note, Name) 
{   
var val = ele.value;    
 if (val == '')
 {      
     note = note +Name+"element can not be Empty; \n";
     return false;
 }
return true;
}

function validateForm() {
var note =  "";
var ele1 = validateInput(document.getElementById('input1'), note, 'From');
var ele2 = validateInput(document.getElementById('input2'), note, 'To');
var ele3 = validateInput(document.getElementById('input3'), note, 'CC');
alert(note);
return (ele1 && ele2 && ele3);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are not references to String object instance.

You should declare the `note` var in parent context:

```
var note = '';
function validateInput(ele, Name) 
{   
var val = ele.value;    
 if (val == '')
 {      
     note = note +Name+"element can not be Empty; \n";
     return false;
 }
return true;
}

function validateForm() {
note =  "";
var ele1 = validateInput(document.getElementById('input1'), 'From');
var ele2 = validateInput(document.getElementById('input2'), 'To');
var ele3 = validateInput(document.getElementById('input3'), 'CC');
alert(note);
return (ele1 && ele2 && ele3);  
}
```

Comment: The value of `note` is going to get overwritten each time you hit `note = note +Name+"element can not be Empty; \n";`. Use `+=` instead. But I'd avoid using a global variable unless absolutely necessary (which in this case it isn't).

Comment: `note = note +` is strictly the same than `note +=`. I agree with global variables, that's why I spoke about "parent context". That parent context should be under a namespace.

Comment: Hi Ulflander & muscial_coder , both are working fine. I can not select both as answers and also i can not upvote as well(required reputation is not present). thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object to pass values by reference, but for this it isn't necessary. Try this:

```
function validateInput(ele, Name) 
{   
     var val = ele.value;        
     return val == '' ? note +Name+"element can not be Empty; \n" : "";
}

function validateForm() {
var note =  "";
note += validateInput(document.getElementById('input1'), 'From');
note += validateInput(document.getElementById('input2'), 'To');
note += validateInput(document.getElementById('input3'), 'CC');
var isValid = note == "";
if( !isValid )
    alert(note);
return isValid;  
}
```